# Access information inside Constructors

Tags: c++

Example class....

```
class Student
{
    private: 
        int AmtClass;
    public:
        Student(int AmtClass);
}


Student::Student(int amount)
{
    AmtClass = amount;

    string *CName;
    CName = new string[AmtClass];
}

int main()
{
    int amount;
    string Names[amount];
    cin >> amount;
    Student stud(amount);

    for(int i = 0; i > amount; i++)
    {
        getline(cin,Names[i]);
        //How can I access the constructor from here?
    }
}
```

How do I access the array of strings inside the constructor? I want to put the course names inside the constructor.

Comment: Please submit code that actually compiles, so we have somewhere to start.

Comment: Don't think I can submit a code that actually compiles if I've never finished it yet, I am just asking how I can access my constructor inside the Int main.

Comment: I highly recommend you start using `std::vector` instead of `new[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `CName` variable is only declared in the local scope of your constructor mehtod:

```
Student::Student(int amount)
{
    AmtClass = amount;

    string *CName; // <<<
    pName = new string[AmtClass]; // <<< Just leaks memory, nothing else
}
```

You probably meant to have it being a class member variable. Also note there's no need for a `string*` pointer or `new`, just use a `std::vector` instead:

```
class Student
{
private: 
    int AmtClass;
    std::vector<std::string> > StudentNames;
public:
    Student(int numStudents);
}

Student::Student(int numStudents) 
: AmtClass(numStudents)
{
    StudentNames.resize(AmtClass);
}
```

After this constructor was called, you can access `StudentNames[i]` where `i` is in the range of [0-AmtClass[, in subsequently called methods from your `Student` class.

All of that said, this would also suggest to name your class `Students` to reflect the intended plural semantics correctly.
Or even better, this should be named `Class` holding a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Student> >`, where `Student` is supposed to have a `std::string` member `name`.

[**OK, here we go:**](http://ideone.com/R6wYQY)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

class Student {
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    Student(const std::string& name_) : name(name_) {}
    const std::string& getName() const { return name; }
};
```

---

```
class Class {
private:
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Student>> SubscriptionList;
    SubscriptionList students;
    const unsigned int MaxSubscribers;

public:
    Class(unsigned int maxSubscribers) : MaxSubscribers(maxSubscribers) {}

    bool subscribe(std::shared_ptr<Student>& student) {
        if(students.size() >= MaxSubscribers) {
            return false; // Class is full, can't subscribe
        }

        // May be put additional checks here, to prevent multiple subscrptions
        students.push_back(student);
        return true; // Sucessfully subscribed the class
    }

    void unsubscribe(std::shared_ptr<Student>& student) {
        SubscriptionList::iterator it = students.begin();
        for(;it != students.end();++it) {
            if(it->get() == student.get()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        students.erase(it);
    }

    void showSubscribedStudents(std::ostream& os) {
        unsigned int i = 1;
        for(SubscriptionList::iterator it = students.begin();
            it != students.end();
            ++it, ++i) {
            os << i << ". " << (*it)->getName() << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

---

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int amount;
    std::cin >> amount;
    std::cin.ignore();

    Class theClass(amount);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        std::string name;
        std::getline(std::cin,name);
        std::shared_ptr<Student> student(new Student(name));
        theClass.subscribe(student);
    }

    theClass.showSubscribedStudents(std::cout);
}
```

Input:

```
5
John Doe
Jane Doe
Aldo Willis
Chuck Norris
Mia Miles
```

Output:

```
1. John Doe
2. Jane Doe
3. Aldo Willis
4. Chuck Norris
5. Mia Miles
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare pName as member variable of the class. Then you can store the input in the pName array during taking the input.

```
class Student
{
    public:
        int AmtClass;
        string *pName;

        Student(int AmtClass);
};


Student::Student(int amount)
{
    AmtClass = amount;
    pName = new string[AmtClass];
}

int main()
{
    int amount;
    string Names;
    cin >> amount;
    getline(cin,Names);
    Student stud(amount);


    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        getline(cin,Names);
        stud.pName[i] = Names;
        //How can I access the constructor from here?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to keep it close to the original code. The user can get the idea. He can use whatever he wants.

Comment: In this case, you should at least extend your answer's sample to be **fully** correct by means of the [rule-of-three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and not leaking memory from the missing destructor!